# Playing an MP3 with Video.js

Tags: javascript, video, video.js

I have been able to dynamically load video with Video.js, but I have heard Video.js also supports mp3 playback. I have this function to test...

```
openMediaModal: function(type, src) {
        //set up modal
        var modal;
        //if video...
        if (type == 'video') {
            modal =  '<div class="modal-wrapper media '+type+'"><div class="modal">';
            modal += '<video id="modal-player" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264" poster="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.png">';
            modal += '<source src="'+src+'" type="video/mp4" />';
            modal += '</video>';
            modal += '</div></div>';
        } else if (type == 'audio') {
            modal =  '<audio id="modal-player" controls>';
            modal += '<source src="'+src+'" type="audio/mpeg">';
            modal += '</audio>';
        } else if (type == "flash") {

        }
        //append modal to page
        crc.body.append(modal);
        //init video
        videojs("modal-player", {}, function(){
            // Player (this) is initialized and ready.
        });
    },
```

Video works fine, but audio throws an error. How do I load in an mp3 for playback dynamically? It doesnt seem to be documented. Thanks.

Comment: Use https://github.com/dz0ny/AudioJS instead.

Comment: Thanks! Is it a replacement for Video.JS? Or is it just a separate script with no interaction with Video.JS?

Comment: Since it is a fork of Video.JS, I'm assuming that they are very similar libraries. I don't think there should be any conflict, considering they have different purposes.